# How to move the <head> code injected by a plugin below the default Wordpress <head> code?

Tags: plugins

Or more specifically, how to move the  code injected by a plugin below Wordpress Jquery?

The plugin, Thrive Visual Editor, has a landing page builder, which allows the insertion of scripts and stylesheets via `Thrive Content Builder > Landing Page settings > Setup custom scripts`.

The custom scripts I've inserted into the landing page need to be presented after Wordpress Jquery for those scripts to work.

I'm not a developer, or a Wordpress developer, I'm a builder/designer.

I've searched the plugin folder for instances of `add_action('wp_head'` and found none. From my limited understanding of Wordpress hooks, I was thinking I could find the instance of `add_action('wp_head'` where the custom scripts were being inserted by the plugin into the `<head>`, and modify its priority below the Wordpress Jquery.

So, my questions are:

- Is there a standard method a plugin injects code into the front end `<head>`?
- How would I change the priority of this insertion so that it occurs after Wordpress Jquery?

I've Googled how Plugins insert their code into the `<head>` and can't find an answer.

***Update***: I searched the plugin folder for `wp_enqueue_scripts` and found in 
`thrive-visual-editor/thrive-visual-editor.php`:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'tve_add_settings_menu');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tve_frontend_enqueue_scripts');
add_filter('tve_landing_page_content', 'tve_editor_content');
```

I searched for `tve_frontend_enqueue_scripts` and found nothing applicable.

I searched for `tve_landing_page_content` and found in `\thrive-visual-editor\landing-page\layout.php`:

```
<body>
...
<?php echo apply_filters( 'tve_landing_page_content', '' ) ?>
...
```

`layout.php` appears to be the template file to replace the theme's page templates - it's a full HTML+PHP web page.

In the `<head>` was:

```
<?php $tcb_landing_page->head(); ?>
```

So, it looks like this is where the custom scripts are inserted.

There is no `wp_head()` in the `<head>` of `layout.php`

In `\thrive-visual-editor\landing-page\inc\TCB_Landing_Page.php` there is:

```
public function head() {
    /* I think the favicon should be added using the wp_head hook and not like this */
    if (function_exists('thrive_get_options_for_post')) {
        $options = thrive_get_options_for_post();
        if (!empty($options['favicon'])) : ?>
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $options['favicon']; ?>"/>
        <?php endif;
    }

    $this->fonts();

    if (!empty($this->globalScripts['head'])) {
        $this->globalScripts['head'] = $this->removeJQuery($this->globalScripts['head']);
        echo $this->globalScripts['head'];
    }

    empty($this->globals['do_not_strip_css']) ?
        $this->stripHeadCss() : wp_head();

    /* finally, call the tcb_landing_head hook */
    apply_filters(self::HOOK_HEAD, $this->id);
}
```

Comment: Can people comment on why they down vote on this SE so I don't keep asking unacceptable questions?

Comment: Don't take downvotes too personally. In the beginning it looks like your question is about a specific plugin, that may have triggered the downvote.

Comment: search for `function head` as `->head()` is a class method (function) call... also worth checking for `wp_add_inline_script`

Comment: @majick: you're right, I've added `function head` to the question. Thanks.

Comment: `wp_add_inline_script` was not found in the plugin.

Comment: Contact the plugin author

Comment: Plugin author declines to help. I've added a job on Upwork. @PieterGoosen.

Comment: We are not an alternative means to sort out some crap from a crappy plugin if the author does not want to help. Close voted and downvoted as off topic

Comment: yes the author should have an option to disable jquery not force it off like this, in the meanwhile just comment out the code inside `function removeJQuery`

Answer (score 3):

Scripts must be inserted using [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/). This function allows you to define dependencies, so you can be sure they load after jquery. Like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script('your-script-name', 'full-path-to-your-script', array('jquery'));
```

Even better, [register](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/) your script first. Anyway, look in the plugin code where it enqueues user scripts and make sure it adds the jquery dependency. Or, perhaps better, build a child theme and add the following to `functions.php`:

```
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts','wpse229008_add_scripts');
function wpse229008_add_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('your-script-name', 'full-path-to-your-script', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('your-script-name');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. When I create a landing page using Thrive Content Editor, the landing page does not use the active theme at all it uses TCE's HTML/PHP/CSS, so the theme's `functions.php` does not have an effect on the landing page.

Comment: I'm afraid since I don't know TCE, I can't help you with that problem. There's no such thing as a child plugin, so you would have to dive into the code of the plugin itself...

Comment: Thanks. See my edit to the question please. Your answer found the culprit for me. Now I just need to know how to have Wordpress Jquery enqueued after `<?php $tcb_landing_page->head(); ?>`.

Comment: If there's no `wp_head` it isn't Wordpress that is loading the jquery. It must be the plugin itself.